# Show Error message

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to try to get if playername exist it should give a message that name exist try other playername
If not exist then it should give successful inserted to db.

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $playername = $_POST['playername'];
    $messagetosend = $_POST['messagetosend'];
    $svar = $_POST['svar'];
    $sentmessage = $_POST['sentmessage'];
    $datum = $_POST['datum'];

    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO rekrytering (playername, messagetosend, svar, sentmessage, datum) VALUES ('$playername', '$messagetosend', '$svar', '$sentmessage', '$datum')"); 
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Player saved";
    $_SESSION['playername'] = "Player Name Exist";
    header('location: index.php');

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

In order to show the result of the `INSERT` query, you need to use [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php):

Change:

```
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO rekrytering (playername, messagetosend, svar, sentmessage, datum) VALUES ('$playername', '$messagetosend', '$svar', '$sentmessage', '$datum')");
```

To:

```
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO rekrytering (playername, messagetosend, svar, sentmessage, datum) VALUES ('$playername', '$messagetosend', '$svar', '$sentmessage', '$datum')") or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Yet another way to do the same is as follows--

```
if(!mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO rekrytering (playername, messagetosend, svar, sentmessage, datum) VALUES ('$playername', '$messagetosend', '$svar', '$sentmessage', '$datum')")) {
    echo("Error occurred: " . mysqli_error($db));
}
```

All that said, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, as you are using the `$_POST` values directly inside your `INSERT` statement.

I highly recommend that you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities etc.

One of the must read is: [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection (PHP)](http://bobby-tables.com/php)